# Sprockets require file from parent directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am trying to use the rails 3.1 asset pipeline to include a javascript file from the manifest file's parent directory

app/assets/javascripts/folder/index.js

```
//=require ../file
```

yields: `couldn't find file 'file'`

How do I require a file from the parent directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Assets in Sprockets are always referenced by their logical path.`

So you just have to use `//=require file` if your file is in `/app/assets/javascripts`.

If your file was `/lib/assets/javascripts/models/lala.js` for instance, you would require it with `//=require models/lala`.